# Generating random letter

Tags: java, random

I want to enter a letter or number and generate a random output (letter or number). And output should also be always same for same input. Can someone please guide me that how can I generate this random output with this specific range.

Comment: And output should also be always same for same input.? What is the use of random?

Comment: an example may be useful

Comment: @Jayan, maybe he means random associations.

Comment: I want to use it for masking. ok forget about this part. please just suggest me how can I generate random alphabets according to the input

Comment: @Jayan This is called pseudo random generation. Most modern languages provide such functionality (for java you need to pass in seed, for C++ `rand()` is like that by default). Pseudorandom generations are very useful especially if you want to reproduce a case second time.

Comment: and example would be like if i enter A and if it generate H then everytime I enter A it should generate H. I know this can be done by setting the seed. I am having problem with controling the range of random output which would be alphabets or numbers only.

Comment: @BorisStrandjev How is it pseudo random ? If he wants the same output every time for the same input , then the randomness is gone altogether.

Comment: @angryInsomniac It is random in the sense that you can not predict it yourself. Pseudo in the sense that for same input same output is generated. Once again this is like most modern compiler random generators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I will make the case of String input equivalent to the one with integer: the simplest way I can think of is to use `str.hashCode()` every object in Java defines this method and it is very easy way to generate an integer from any kind of input.

So now lets assume you have to generate random string based on a single given integer `seed. You can do that:

```
public String  generateString(int seed) {
   Random rnd = new Random(12);
   int len = 10 + rnd.nextInt()  % 20; // achieving random string length in [10, 30)
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); // here we will build the string
   for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        sb.append(32 + (char) rnd.nextInt() % 94); // displayable ASCIs are between 32 and 127
   }
   return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: but does it generate same output for same input? like I input a string "this is test" and taking every character of this string, I generated random alphabet and it generates different outputs for same inputs...I used 65+rand.nextInt((int)c)%24 for random generation.

Comment: e.g. "this is test" it should generate same characters for all i's and s's but it does not. what am I doing wrong? and for testing I set the seed as 2 by rand.setseed(2)

Comment: Hmm maybe I misunderstood your task. I thought that if I take the input string as a whole, every time the same random string should be generated for it. The current code can even generate random strings with different length compared to the input string.

Answer (score 1):

The point of random output is "randomness" , if you want a method that generates the same output for the same input , then it is not random at all.

If you just want a method that does input -> (do stuff here) -> output 
Where for any input 'i' , the output 'o' is fixed 
like , if you give 1 as an input you always get 247 (or any other number)
then just make up any mathematical formula (eg. (sin(x) * 73)/43 or tan(x) if you don't want the output to repeat ) where 'x' is your input , this will generate a 'seemingly' unrelated output for any input , which will always be fixed for any given number.

Comment: I see in the comments that you mentioned that you want to do this for characters , this aproach can be easily modified for the same where you do (char) (32+((((tan((int)x)* 53)/42))%26))

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood you correct, maybe this is want you are trying to do.

```
import java.util.Random;
class t
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Random rand = new Random(100);

        char[] alpha = new char[26];    //to store alpahbets
        int[] rlist = new int[26];      //to store random numbers


        for (int j = 0; j<26; j++)
        {
            alpha[j] = (char)(j+97);
            rlist[j] = rand.nextInt(10);
            System.out.println(rlist[j]);
        }

        //input
        char input = 'a';
        //output
        int loc = (int)input-97;
        System.out.println(alpha[rlist[loc]]);
    }
}
```

You could very well use a hashtable.